# Is it possible to change return type when intercepting a method?

Tags: c#, .net, aop, interceptor

I'd like to treat mapping of data access objects to domain objects as a cross cutting concern and solve the problem using AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming). What I like to do is intercept the repository class and do the mapping in the handler class.

```
public List<PersonEntity> GetAll()
{
    List<PersonDao> daoPersons = FetchAll();

    return daoPersons; 
}

public class MapperCallHandler<TEntity> : ICallHandler
{
public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
{
    IMethodReturn msg = getNext()(input, getNext);

    msg.ReturnValue = Mapper.Map<TEntity>(msg.ReturnValue);   

    return msg;
}

}
```

The compiler doesn't like this. It's the wrong type returned from the `GetAll()` method.

If a change return type on the `GetAll()` method to `List<PersonDao>` it does't work in runtime since the handler changes the type of the objects returned from the `GetAll()` method to `List<PersonEntity>`.

I did solve this by returning `List<object>` from the `GetAll()` method, but then I have to do an explicit cast in the class calling the method.

Is there a way to achive this without doing the explicit cast? Or is it impossible to change return type in a handler incepting a method?

Comment: What is the class relationship between PersonDAO and PersonEntity? Do they share any common interfaces (IPerson perhaps?)

Comment: You'd probably need to give us some mor einfo - your `use-case` (how you call/use the 'list', is it just readonly query?) and `the design (classes, inheritance` - can 'you change the code' etc.). That cannot work (in more ways than once) but I'd need some data to post an answer.

Comment: @BrianO''Byrne Your suggestion would solve the problem, but it doesn't answer the question: Is it possible to change return type when intercepting a method? Maybe the answer is no.

Comment: @NSGaga the usage is very simple `var repository = new PersonRepository(); List<PersonEntity> persons = repository .GetAll()`. I can change the code/design all I want.

Comment: I wasnt aware that I made a suggestion. I asked a question in order to understand the problem better. As a rule on any method it is impossible to use a return value that is incompatible with the return type of the method. This is true in any strongly-typed language.